# SQL Sum and grouping with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with sequences, and counts for each item. I'm trying to come up with a query that adds an extra column in the result, such that in the new column each row/item will have the sum of all the items' counts whose sequence is lower than the item.

e.g.:

```
items   [...]   seq    counts
a       [...]    1       1
b       [...]    2       1
c       [...]    3       8
d       [...]    4       2
a       [...]    1       1
e       [...]   null     1
```

result:

```
items   [...]   seq    counts  sum
a       [...]    1       1   (doesnt matter, could be 0 or 1)
b       [...]    2       1      1
c       [...]    3       8      2
d       [...]    4       2     10
a       [...]    1       1   (doesnt matter, could be 0 or 1)
e       [...]   null     1   (doesnt matter)
f       [...]    5       10    12
```

I dont know how to sum up something with a condition like this. I only know how to do group by and sum all the item in a group. Subquery isnt working for me either

Comment: firstly, how the 6th rows `a .. 1  1` is coming at 6th position? Are you using some order by for it? What if this 6th rows comes as 2nd row? Would ur result change?

Comment: in reality it is a huge table with a lot of join, so there are rows with repeated items, seq, counts and sum combination, the [...] columnS contains what make each rows unique. Also the table are not ordered

Comment: There's a condition you're not mentioning. Row 1 & 5 `seq==1` (i.e. `<2`) So why does Row 2 `seq==2` have `sum==1` As per requirement: "_will have the sum of all the items' counts whose sequence is lower than the item_" it should have `sum==2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum.  You can do this using `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.sumcounts
from t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.counts) as sumcounts
      from t t2
      where t2.seq < t.seq
     ) t2;
```